# Why can I not rename the directory of my file?

Tags: java, directory, rename, filewriter

I have a directory that is the name of a "fullName" if the full name is updated, I want to update the directory name as well. How can I rename the directory? Here is my code so far:

```
try
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter new first name: ");
                    firstName = sc.nextLine();

                    File fileLN = new File(fullName + "\\lastName.txt");

                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileLN);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                    lastName = br.readLine();

                    // set new full name
                    newFullName = firstName + lastName;
                    System.out.println(newFullName);    // debug

                    File file = new File(fullName);
                    File newFile = new File(newFullName);
                    if(file.isDirectory())
                    {
                        file.renameTo(newFile);
                        System.out.println("worked");    //debug
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Directory not found");
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: the error is that it isn't renaming the directory. say full name is "John Doe", then I would have a directory named "JohnDoe", if I were to change the first name to "Joe", I want my directory name to update to "JoeDoe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you still have a file open in the directory you're trying to rename. If you're on a Windows based platform, you will get an error trying to do the rename. The solution is to close `fr` before the rename:

```
lastName = br.readLine();
fr.close();
```

Comment: it still didn't rename my directory

Comment: Okay, well, maybe you have another file still open in the directory that you haven't shown us.

Comment: I went through and checked for that, and It seems to have fixed my code, thank you very much!